# Proper way of setting up database for ease of use?

Tags: php, database, database-design, codeigniter

So i'm trying to figure out the smartest way to do this. I have a list of businesses that can have photos and videos. i've created tables for: business, photos, videos. I also created a table for specials. I want to have featured businesses on the front page. Should I create a table called featured and have the businesses id stored in the table and then query the featured table?  What if I want to show on the home page that they have photos and videos?

Comment: both of you had the same idea but axarydax was just a little bit quicker so i chose that one as the answer. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the basic design would be OK, but I would just add column to businesses that specifies if it is featured or now. If  you want to show if featured businesses have videos or photos, ask the database if

```
select count(*) from photos 
join business on photos.businessId = business.id
where id = @featuredBusinessID
```

for each featured one, similar for videos too.

Answer (score 1):

Design your core database to do what you want, and query it in a straightforward manner to get the data you need.  That having been said, for the featured businesses, the easiest way to do it is to put a `featured` field on the business table and get your list of featured businesses by querying for `featured = 1`.  This will be both the simplest and most performant solution (indexing on `featured` will be faster than joining a "featured" table to your businesses table).

To get photo information, just join the results to the `photos` table.  Ditto for video.